# Can I enable HTTP application routing at Azure AKS after being created?

Tags: azure, azure-aks

At the moment the only way I see it possible [according to docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/http-application-routing) is while creating the k8s cluster.

Is there a way that I can change this config for existing cluster?

Comment: use ingress controller(e.g nginx) to route http traffic to cluster https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource

Answer (score 4):

With the latest Azure CLI you should be able to run the following command:

`az aks enable-addons -a http_application_routing -g <RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME>
-n <AKS_CLUSTER_NAME>`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can determine the clients lag behind. The cli has the option in `az aks create`, but there is no `az aks update` command yet. PowerShell (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.aks) on the other hand has `Set-AzureRmAks`, but it doesn't have the option and neither does `New-AzureRmAks`. The underlying REST API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/managedclusters/createorupdate) uses the same operation for create and update and supports it, so if you really need it you may be able to do it by hitting the API directly (not tested). Otherwise we will hopefully get updated clients in a not too distant future.